# How to delete rows flanking a block of zero values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with the raw data from eye tracking software:

[image]

The lines with zeros represent the time when the user is blinking. In a small period before and after the blink, the calibration of the eye tracking device is inaccurate. Therefore I would like to delete the rows that correspond to the blink (with 0 values) AND the 4 rows before and after each blink.

You can recreate a similar df:

```
test <- data.frame(a = sample(0:200, 200, replace = T),
                   b = sample(0:200, 200, replace = T),
                   c = sample(0:200, 200, replace = T),
                   d = sample(0:200, 200, replace = T))
test[50:100, ] <- 0
```

Comment: But, the image is just to give you an idea. You can imagine it should also work on a simple df. check my edit.

Comment: Why only 4 rows? In the image there are at least 8 rows with 0s?

Comment: Because the 4 rows represent each eye and its X and Y coordinate. So GLX = Gaze left x, GLY = Gaze left y. The other rows are not relevant. I will only select GLX, GLY, GRX, GRY and end up with a similar data.frame as test. My only question is, how to delete rows above a row that has a rowsums of 0.

Comment: *My only question is, how to delete rows above a row that has a rowsums of 0*: `which(rowSums(DATA) == 0) - 1` With this you will get those rows. You just need to filter them out.

Comment: @PoGibas 
check <- test %>%
  select(a, b, c, d) %>%
  mutate(n.zeros = rowSums(. == 0.00))

check2 <- check[-which(check$n.zeros >= 3), ]

Comment: To the close voters: it's actually pretty clear what is being asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain R solution.

Following your example dataset. First, a vector denoting where the zeros are:

```
> zeros <- rowSums(test) == 0
> zeros
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [49] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [61]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [73]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [85]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [97]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[109] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[121] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[133] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[145] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[157] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[169] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[181] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[193] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We add some phony false rows so that each actual row has at least four items before and after:

```
> zeros <- c(F, F, F, F, F, zeros, F, F, F, F)
```

Then, compute a rolling sum over a window of 9 (four rows before, the considered row, four rows after):

```
> rolling <- diff(cumsum(zeros), 9)
> rolling
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
 [75] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[149] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[186] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Remove rows that have a non-zero value of neighboring zero rows:

```
> output <- test[rolling == 0, ]
> rownames(output)
  [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22" 
 [23] "23"  "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  "35"  "36"  "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "41"  "42"  "43"  "44" 
 [45] "45"  "105" "106" "107" "108" "109" "110" "111" "112" "113" "114" "115" "116" "117" "118" "119" "120" "121" "122" "123" "124" "125"
 [67] "126" "127" "128" "129" "130" "131" "132" "133" "134" "135" "136" "137" "138" "139" "140" "141" "142" "143" "144" "145" "146" "147"
 [89] "148" "149" "150" "151" "152" "153" "154" "155" "156" "157" "158" "159" "160" "161" "162" "163" "164" "165" "166" "167" "168" "169"
[111] "170" "171" "172" "173" "174" "175" "176" "177" "178" "179" "180" "181" "182" "183" "184" "185" "186" "187" "188" "189" "190" "191"
[133] "192" "193" "194" "195" "196" "197" "198" "199" "200"
```

This can be obviously wrapped in some `dplyr`'s `mutate` or sth, if there is such a desire.

EDIT: fixed an off-by-one.

Comment: Although on first sight I thought this would do, i have a couple of questions. zeros are denoted as TRUE, if we want a vector that has some fake rows with additional zeros, shouldnt we add zeros <- c(T,T,T,T, zeros, T,T,T,T)? Either way, i tried both, and strangely enough they both change row 100-105 into TRUE(fake zeros), but not 45-50. The last 4 rows of the data set, however did change to TRUE..

Comment: @BartR, then I'm not really sure where's the problem. Could you define what's the expected output for your test case? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Iiori the expected output of my test data.frame, is the data.frame without the rows where the rowsums are 0, and delete the 4 rows above and below that block of 0's. So in your example you see rowSums(test) == 0, true for every 0. You then made some phony false rows, but i think in my case that should be TRUE rows, because i want to delete the 4 rows below and above aswell. Anyway, if i try your solotution with c(T,T,T,T,zeros,T,T,T,T) row 100-105 is now also 'seen as zero' but 45-50 is not.. (remember row 50-100 are zeros and i want 45-105 out.

Comment: @BartR, if so, I believe my solution performs exactly that: the output consists of the original rows 1-45 and 104-200 (should be 105-200, but I indeed make a mistake—an off-by-one bug, though; I will edit a fix in). Please compare the `rownames(test)` and `rownames(output)`.

Comment: thanks alot! it does work indeed. However, i still have an offset of 1 row. Instead of 45-105 gap, i have an 44-104 gap. Doesnt really matter tho, but easy way to fix? Again; Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)

vec0s <- which(df$GLX == 0) #vector of zeros
indexToRemove <- map2(vec0s-4, vec0s+4, function(minVal, maxVal) {
  minVal:maxVal %>% #vector of 4 below to 4 above each row with 0
    .[minVal:maxVal > 0] #remove any negative numbers
}) %>% unlist() %>% unique() #select unique numbers in cases of overlap

df <- df[-indexToRemove,] #Remove from df
```